# Send Get and POST request to Azure function app using ajax .NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api

I am developing a .NET application where users can go fill out a request (form). Once the user clicks "Submit". The goal is to send a POST request to a function app (PowerShell powered). If the post request is successful, it would return a id for the request.

I would like to use this Id to query the status of the request (GET) sent to the function app. Once a user hits submit, it should automatically redirect them to the details page where they can view their request status.

Here is my controller I want to route the request to:

```
namespace AzDeployManager.Web.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class DeploymentController : ControllerBase
    {

        public string ReceiveRequest { get; set; }
        public string CheckRequest { get; set; }

        public DeploymentController(IOptions<AppSettings> settings)
        {
            this.ReceiveRequest = settings.Value.AzReceiveRequest;
            this.CheckRequest = settings.Value.AzCheckRequest;
        }

        // POST: api/ReceiveRequest
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("sendrequest")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync([FromBody] Deployment deployment)
        {
            using var http = new HttpClient();
            var data = new Deployment
            {
                
            };

            //var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(deployment));

            var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data));
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

            var request = http.PostAsync(ReceiveRequest, content);

            var response = await request.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return Ok(response);
        }
    }
}
```

In my http post shown in the controller, I am able to view the data by debugging. I am now having issues customizing the payload as I want it:

```
{
   "data": {
       "name1": "val1",
       "name2": "val2"
   },
   "name3": "val3"
}
```

Any guidance will be helpful here.

Comment: How does your Azure function invoke? Which trigger are you using?

Comment: Azure function uses a http trigger (post) and once the request comes in, it would direct the request to its appropriate queue long as its the accepted payload body.

Comment: You don't need to use Azure function if you want to wait for response. If you're just adding data in db via azure function and want to wait for response then why you're not saving data from the application itself? If you don't have any choice then you can call your function using httpclient (https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-and-consume-azure-function-from-asp-net-core/) but you can't get the response back in this way. One option is to wait for 2-3 seconds using Thread.Sleep(3000) and then fetch the last record from db but you never know if there was an error in function.

Comment: the function app in question handles all data processing. Once a request is sent to it, it will add the request to a azure storage table. From the dotnet perspective, I just want to be able to send payload request to this function app > get the request Id and use this request Id to fetch the details of the request in the details page.

Comment: Then see the link I pasted in the above comment. You can use httpclient to invoke your azure function.

Comment: Will this work the same if I add this to my controller instead of my index model ? I have my function values exposed there:

public DeploymentController(IOptions<AppSettings> settings)
        {
            ReceiveRequest = settings.Value.AzReceiveRequest;
            CheckRequest = settings.Value.AzCheckRequest;
        }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229953/discussion-between-bonafide-and-ask).

Comment: Yes, you can use it in controller as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery to serialize the key-value pairs of the form into an array, then parse it into a json object.

```
<script>
    function getdata() {
        var paramArray = $('#submitreq').serializeArray();

        var body = {};
        $(paramArray).each(function () {
            //here 
            if (this.name.indexOf('\.') > 0) {
                body[this.name.split('\.')[1]] = this.value;
            } else {
                body[this.name] = this.value;
            }
        });
        
        body['RequestNumber'] = parseInt(body['RequestNumber'])
        
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/api/sendrequest",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(body),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (response) {
                console.log("Success: " + response.RequestNumber);
            },
            error: function (req, status, error) {
                console.log("Error occured: " + status + "" + req.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Because the fieldset is set to disabled, it will not be automatically serialized, you can add a hidden input box outside the fieldset.

```
<form id="submitreq" method="post">
  <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

  <input type="hidden" asp-for="Deployment.RequestNumber" class="form-control" />

<!--...-->
  <input type="button" name="name" value="submit" onclick="getdata()" />
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: I was able to progress and route my form to the api. Its actually "api/Deployment/sendrequest". Upon debugging, it doesn't look like my controller (per your gif) has any values its all empty. Any guidance here?

Comment: Is there a problem during serialization? Can you share the captures(serialized string) after it is serialized?

Comment: see - https://imgur.com/a/GUG6kCq. I believe it could be my create.cshtml.cs file causing the issue. I want to route all GET and POST requests to the controller for reusability purposes.

Comment: @bonafide, this is not the jsonarray in the view, can you share the format after you run `$('#submitreq').serializeArray()`.

Comment: The image could not show when I access. Can you reshare it?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/9e19BtY - the array has values included. Not all form fields are being captured eg: dropdown fields for choices.

Comment: What is the result when you use `JSON.stringify(body)`?

Comment: JSON.stringify(body) = 
"{"rgName":"demo-rg","subscriptionId":"c223f120-9e24-4fe4-802a-ae5bc93fe41e","environment":"dev","location":"eastus","operation":"rgcreate"}"

Comment: From your capture, I think I have found the error, because the name is not mathced with the model, you can refert to the edited answer (**in $(paramArray).each(function () {**).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229959/discussion-between-bonafide-and-karney).